# Google Maps - Create a polygon around existing markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, polygon

I dont know if this is possible but I use a google map to plot out positions of entities via markers on an overlay. I would like to be able to create a polygon or some other sort of overlay object around all the created markers, highlighting the extent of the markers, sort of a catchment area diagram. I wont know before all the markers are retrieved from the database and mapped what the extent is.

Anyone have any ideas how to approach this..?

Thanks

Comment: Well it's possible. What have you tried?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [Convex Hull of the points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull)

> In mathematics, the convex hull or convex envelope of a set X of points in the Euclidean plane or Euclidean space is the smallest convex set that contains X. For instance, when X is a bounded subset of the plane, the convex hull may be visualized as the shape enclosed by a rubber band stretched around X.

[Example using the Google Maps API v3 on a random set of points](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_map-markers_ConvexHull.asp)