# Programmatically drawing polygons on a map by joining the outermost markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygon, google-fusion-tables, layer

I have a sample map layer in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7GP7E/1/) where the map layer is drawn using fusion table as,

```js
var Layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
       select: 'lat',
       from: '1BLPDF4n0sW0i0BfD9Yo0DqbshyTH1s5Iuu_1IeU'
    },
    map: map,
    suppressInfoWindows: true
});
```

How can I draw a polygon programmatically by joining the outermost markers in the map so that if someone add new marker and if it is falling outside the drawn polygon then automatically the polygon should redraw to include the newly added marker too.

Comment: What do you mean by "outermost" here? There is many ways you can draw a polygon based on the Lat,Long data from the above dataset. They describe powerlines / transformers (I guess) connected to a railway station. The data is in no logically order, and what could seem "outermost" vary completely depending of how you order the data.

Comment: The term "Outermost" meant that the polygon that drawn by joining line between outer markers (considering atmost minimum number) that ensures the markers resides within the polygon. Something like shown in this image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/EyCfD.png

Comment: Exactly my point! That is not possible without some logic / rules. You have just drawed by hand, randomly - not after any rule. Look at your own picture - why do you include the 2th top left red dot, but not the 2th bottom left yellow dot? Just one example.

Comment: I just drawn a sample. There are many ways to connect the lines between points to draw a polygon. But I like to know if there any programmatic ways to achieve the same. May be best suggestions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps - Create a polygon around existing markers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383807/google-maps-create-a-polygon-around-existing-markers)

Comment: In my sample map I guess minimum 7 markers required to draw a polygon viz 4 red markers, 2 blue markers and one yellow marker.

Comment: @user3102065, yeah - thats another mystery. Where did the red, blue and yellow distinction come from? Looked at the data, there are no such grouping or columns just have 3 different values. Besides that, you dont event have to `select : 'lat'` to get the same result.

Comment: The group is done based on the column named `Feeder` in the data. Also It is just a sample data set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to do a [Convex Hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of your points.

[Example using the Google Maps API v3 on a random set of points](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_map-markers_ConvexHull.asp)

[image: Picture of Convex Hull result]

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/pqkhsoLu/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var gmarkers = [];
var points = [];
var hullPoints = [];
var map = null;
var polyline;

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50)
});

function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    },
    navigationControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.close();
  });

  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    // Add 10 markers to the map at random locations
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
    var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
    var lngSpan = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng();
    var latSpan = northEast.lat() - southWest.lat();
    map.setCenter(map.getCenter());
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1);
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(southWest.lat() + latSpan * Math.random(),
        southWest.lng() + lngSpan * Math.random());
      points.push(point);
      var marker = createMarker(point, i);
      gmarkers.push(marker);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
      document.getElementById("input_points").innerHTML += i + ": " + points[i].toUrlValue() + "<br>";
    }
    calculateConvexHull();
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(evt) {
    if (evt.latLng) {
      var latlng = evt.latLng;
      var marker = createMarker(latlng, gmarkers.length - 1);
      points.push(latlng);
      gmarkers.push(marker);
      calculateConvexHull();
    }
  });
}

function removeMarker(latlng) {
  for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
    if (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(
        latlng, gmarkers[i].getPosition()) < 0.1) {
      gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
      gmarkers.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  calculateConvexHull();
}

function createMarker(latlng, marker_number) {
  var html = "marker " + marker_number;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat() * -100000) << 5
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    var contentString = html + "<br>" + marker.getPosition().toUrlValue() + "<br><a href='javascript:removeMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(" + marker.getPosition().toUrlValue() + "));'>Remove Marker</a>";
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  return marker;
}

function calculateConvexHull() {
  if (polyline) polyline.setMap(null);
  document.getElementById("hull_points").innerHTML = "";
  points = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
    points.push(gmarkers[i].getPosition());
  }
  points.sort(sortPointY);
  points.sort(sortPointX);
  DrawHull();
}

function sortPointX(a, b) {
  return a.lng() - b.lng();
}

function sortPointY(a, b) {
  return a.lat() - b.lat();
}

function DrawHull() {
  hullPoints = [];
  chainHull_2D(points, points.length, hullPoints);
  polyline = new google.maps.Polygon({
    map: map,
    paths: hullPoints,
    fillColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeWidth: 2,
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    strokeColor: "#0000FF",
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  displayHullPts();
}

function displayHullPts() {
  document.getElementById("hull_points").innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < hullPoints.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("hull_points").innerHTML += hullPoints[i].toUrlValue() + "<br>";
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<script src="http://www.geocodezip.com/scripts/convex_hull.js"></script>
<h2>Convex Hull of random set of points</h2>
<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button onclick="polyline.setMap(null);">hide polygon</button>
      <button onclick="calculateConvexHull();">calculate Convex Hull</button>
      <button onclick="displayHullPts();">display Hull Points</button>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
      <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
      <table border="1" width="100%">
        <tr>
          <th>random pts</th>
          <th>hull points</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top">
            <div id="input_points"></div>
          </td>
          <td valign="top">
            <div id="hull_points"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="info"></div>
```