# Draw a border as a radius in google map with multiple markers

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I am facing a problem with google map, to draw a border line arround the multiple markers area range.i have a reference site, i want to draw like refernce site.
You can check this [URL](http://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-search/Fresno_CA?pos=36.669743,-120.143374,36.967123,-119.514406,11) .
I tried to create same border using poliline but line is following marker postion.
You can check my [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pkufpssL/) .
Working Code:

```
function initMap(){
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
zoom: 10,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.520, 13.410),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});  
var flightPlanCoordinates = [
 {lat: 52.511, lng: 13.447},
    {lat: 52.549, lng: 13.422},
    {lat: 52.497, lng: 13.396},
    {lat: 52.517, lng: 13.394}
];  
var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
path: flightPlanCoordinates,
geodesic: true,
strokeColor: '#FF0000',
strokeOpacity: 1.0,
strokeWeight: 2
});
flightPath.setMap(map);  
var marker, i;
for (i = 0; i < flightPlanCoordinates.length; i++) {  
console.log();
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(flightPlanCoordinates[i].lat, flightPlanCoordinates[i].lng),
map: map
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
return function() {
  infowindow.setContent('text');
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
}
})(marker, i));
}  
}
```

So i need to know reference site boarder is created by polinine or any thing else.

See Screenshot :
[image: Map Sreenshot]
I need your help so that i can achive my goal.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any map on your reference [URL](http://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-search/Fresno_CA?pos=36.669743,-120.143374,36.967123,-119.514406,11), please make your question complete without referring to external URLs that may change or die.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps - Create a polygon around existing markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383807/google-maps-create-a-polygon-around-existing-markers)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically drawing polygons on a map by joining the outermost markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678563/programmatically-drawing-polygons-on-a-map-by-joining-the-outermost-markers)

Comment: Hi thank you for check my issue, well still URL si correct there is right side area with a Map button.When you click on it it will display all markers on map.
But now its my mistake i need to add screenshot for this result.
I am going to add screenshot for map.